# Just downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu. How do I actually install it?

Tags: system-installation

Just downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu, What do I do now?

I see where it is downloaded in my downloaded folder, but how do I run this operating system?

Comment: What is your current operating system? UEFI installation is way different than a basic BIOS install. First, make a backup of all your current stuff in case something goes wrong.

Comment: and 14.04 is NOT the latest.

Comment: Well, I just got a New Laptop, which is a Acer Aspire R 15, and it is running Windows 10. I just got it today. My intentions were to partition the hard drive, and make Ubuntu my main operating system, and just use Windows periodically whenever I needed to. I am new to computers, as my specialty are smart phones. So I am learning as I go. I developed a passion for Linux after I used it a few times on my cousins computer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depneds a little bit on if you have a optical drive on the maschine that you want to install ubuntu  on or not. For this answer I assume you have a optical drive.

- Burn the image you downloaded on a DVD
- Reboot you maschine you may need to change your booting devive most newer maschine allow so by pressing `F8` during boot (this may be even before your monitor is back from stand by)
- in the bootmenu of your dvd choose install ubuntu and press `return`
- read the messagenes and instructions on the screen carfully and proseed as you wish

From this point on the way how to proseed exactly differ based on your goals. This anwser can be expanded for your situation if you update your question.

Comment: Thank you Kupferdrache, I appreciate your response. As I just mention in the comment above, I just got a Acer Aspire R 15. My intentions right off the bat were to partition the hard drive, making Ubuntu my main operating system, and Windows 10 my second operating system. I donnot have a DVD/CD drive, so I will just do what you said through the use of a USB drive. Think it will work? Thanks!

Comment: make sure you boot the stick in UEFI mode.As it is a quite new laptop, check the hardware databases, if you have something to have your attention used (eg. Monitor brightness is not regulatable). You are welcome.